# Stop visual studio complaing Razor and JQuery

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, razor

I have a razor view with the following JQuery

```
var patientAccessNotificationHub;
$.cookie.json = true;
var username = "@this.Context.User.Identity.Name.Replace("\\", "\\\\")";

$(function () {
    $(function () {
    //Set the hubs URL to the location of the siganlr server e.g http://localhost:8900/signalr
    $.connection.hub.url = "@(notificationServerUrl)";

    accessNotificationHub = @string.Format("$.connection.{0};", HubNames.accessNotificationHub);
```

Visual Studio highlights this as a syntax error are the string format is done in razor while the script is javascript. The code works when the applications is run.

I can get rid of the syntax error by surrounding it quotes (as the line above is), unfortunately that results in the resulting variable being a string and not executing. Is there a way to format this to make both the syntax checker and the code execute correctly?

Comment: Put it in a `data-` attribute and read it from there in JS.

Comment: JS that is a possibility, it just feels like there should be some way to do this inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in my workplace as well.

Ignore it. You should never code around a static analyzer, it has no affect on the correctness of your application.

It doesn't help you in any way to obfuscate your intent by trying to outsmart the static analyzer (which is being incredibly dumb at the moment). Would you rather have a metric that's clearly not working properly give you a green checkmark or have clean, direct code that makes sense to the developers when they look at it?

Comment: I just suspected/hoped that there might be a way to have both clean code with no reported errors

Comment: I hoped so as well, but in the past 3 months no one in my workplace has determined a way to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @CBauer's answer is good general advice, but at least in this one particular scenario, I think the difficulty can be overcome with a couple of minor changes that don't affect the readability or maintainability of your code.

1. Since JavaScript is not opinionated as to what type of quotes you use as string delimiters, use single-quotes around the Razor syntax:

   ```
   var username = '@this.Context.User.Identity.Name.Replace("\\", "\\\\")';
   ```
2. If that alone is not enough, you can give Razor a little extra help in picking out what belongs to it for parsing purposes using the `@()` syntax:

   ```
   var username = '@(this.Context.User.Identity.Name.Replace("\\", "\\\\"))';
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately @Chris Pratt, your second suggestion did not change the compiler warning (Syntax error) on the pages I have that also display this bad behavior. My code looks like: `var defaultYMin = @(Model.CostEntryViewModels.Min(model => model.UnitCost)) * 0.9;` with visual studio complaining on the *.

Comment: Yeah. Like i said, it should help the OP's specific problem, but otherwise, your advice tends to be the only route that makes sense. You *could* set a variable with the Razor code and then do the multiplication on a separate line after, but that gets into the territory of changing the code just to satisfy the syntax processor.